# How to mock mongoose model method with TypeMoq?

Tags: mongoose, tdd, typemock, typemoq

I tried with

```
const mock = TypeMoq.Mock.ofInstance(userModel)
mock
    .setup(x => x.findOne(TypeMoq.It.isAny()))
    .returns(() => ({username: 'test', gender: 'female'}))
```

But it doesn't work.

- It claims that userModel doesn't have an `findOne` method
- The returns won't pass compilation because `{username: 'test', gender: 'female'}` is not a `DocumentQuery` object.

Comment: I am not sure you can mock mongoose with typeMoq but you can use alternatives https://github.com/alonronin/mockingoose